# MAC Address valid?

Tags: networking, mac-address

I have a Network POS Printer I am using for a project and I need to give my router its MAC and it said the MAC is invalid? Any advice if there may be different forms of MAC address? Google isn't helping.
MAC is 0-0-53-70-87-104 apparently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mac addresses are represented in hexadecimal and not decimal. The last numeral 104 is too big. Your converted adress is `00-00-35-46-57-68`.

Answer (score 1):

MAC addresses always contain groups of two (2) hexadecimal digits. IT should look more like this:

`00-53-70-87-10-40`

Se the Wikipedia article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAC_address